# How to place an image in D3 node?

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, hyperlink, nodes

So far I have created these D3 nodes that are used to create a collapsible hierarchical tree. So far these nodes are coloured #AA1C1C (dark red) to show that if you click on them, they will expand into more nodes. What I want to do is use place in image in the node which will be a plus symbol to all the user to know it's clickable. How do I do this? I was trying to use this symbol: http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/ionicons/svg/ios7-plus-outline.svg

**D3**

```
nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  .attr("r", 6.2)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "blue" : "#fff";
```

});

**SVG:**

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Am I on the right lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You tried to create a collapsible tree and you need to add image in nodes, so I modify [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example and create some codes.

1. For the first step custom your json or data like this:

   ```
   var data = {
           "fname": "Rachel",
            "lname": "Rogers",
            "title": "CEO",
             "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/cats/1",
            "children": [{
            "fname": "Bob",
              "lname": "Smith",
            "title": "President",
              "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/cats/2",
            "children": [{
                "fname": "Mary",
                  "lname": "Jane",
                   "title": "Vice President",
                  "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/cats/3",
            "children": [{
                 "fname": "Bill",
                  "lname": "August",
                   "title": "Dock Worker",
                  "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/cats/4"
            }, {
                "fname": "Reginald",
                 "lname": "Yoyo",
                 "title": "Line Assembly",
                "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/cats/5"
            }]
           }, {
              "fname": "Nathan",
               "lname": "Ringwald",
               "title": "Comptroller",
               "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/60/60/cats/6"
           }]
          }]
        }
   ```

   2. Modify your code.

**---Update---**

Regular way to show clickable Object in JavaScript is working with `CSS` class.
As you can see in my jsfiddle code I used `.node { cursor: pointer;}` to show this node is clickable. you can change your code like this:

```
   nodeUpdate.select("circle")
               .attr("r", 6.2)
               .style("filter", function(d) { 
                   return d._children ? "url(#image)" : "#fff"; 
                }).on("mouseover",function(d){
                           d3.select(this).style("cursor","pointer");
                });
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/7byrw3p5/).

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) link could help you.

**---Update---**

I modify my code to read data from `json` file. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VxwY1Mc5UYusvhYic8u) is the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, how do I just pull the images from the JSON? I only want the nodes with children to have images

Comment: You can filter and select children and parent with this code:                                                         `var children = nodes.filter(function(d) {
            return !d.children;
        });
        var parents = nodes.filter(function(d) {
            return d.children;
        });`

Comment: As you can see in my jsfiddle code I used json example in my code. if you mean you like to read `json` file, just past my data to `json` file and add `d3.json()` to your code.  [This](http://bl.ocks.org/billdwhite/7028521) link could help you to learn all of this comments.

Comment: I update my code to read data from json file. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/0VxwY1Mc5UYusvhYic8u) link is updated code with json file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a pattern if you are going to use a fill.

```js
var box = d3.select('svg')
  .append('svg:circle')
  .attr('cx', 60)
  .attr('cy', 60)
  .attr('r', 10)
  .style('fill', 'url(#image)')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="660">
  <defs id="mdef">
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" height="40" width="40">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" xlink:href="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/ionicons/svg/ios7-plus-outline.svg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

You could also do it with filters

```js
d3.select('svg')
  .append('svg:circle')
  .attr('cx', 60)
  .attr('cy', 60)
  .attr('r', 20)
  .style('filter', 'url(#image)')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="660">
  <filter id="image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feImage xlink:href="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/ionicons/svg/ios7-plus-outline.svg" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Note that you just need the .style('fill', 'url(#image)') or .style('filter', 'url(#image)') and the markup within the svg from the above. The rest of the javascript is just for adding a sample circle.

Once you've added it to the svg, you can reuse both multiple times.

Comment: hoe come I already have a fill with the red colour, why do I need a pattern? these suggestions aren't working for me

Comment: What do you see when you add the above to your code? (btw the pattern / filter is an image)

Comment: it just doesn't load the image? Okay so I put the filter image in my html, then I place .style('filter', 'url(#image)') in my d3 code? I don't need to set the sizes because I've already set them elsewhere

Comment: Would you mind posting your code in a fiddle or part of it? Btw, do you see anything when you click 'Run code snippet' in the answer?

Comment: I've got the code working however the image doesn't load. I can't get fiddler working because I have an external json and don't know how to connect it. I'll update my code above

Comment: huh? Why do you have your filter directly under the body like that - if you look at the code and code snippet they are supposed to be inside the svg element. Add an svg element, put the filter IN the svg element (like it's shown in the answer and the code snippet). Then have d3 add your graph or chart to a named svg element. Btw you also have d3 included twice.

Comment: I don't have the svg inside the html, I have it in the js